# Swift: Is there an alternative to using nested dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm not a swift developer, sorry if this is a silly question, but is there a clean alternative to using nested dictionaries in swift or would this be the way to go? I've been trying different data structures for a while now, but I can't replicate something like this:

```
let locations = [
    "west": [
        "california": [
            [ 3, 0, 1]
        ],
        "oregon": [
            [2, 0, 1]
        ]
    ],
    "east": [
        "new york": [
            [ 3, 0, 2]
        ],
        "florida": [
            [2, 0, 2]
        ]
    ]
]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a clean way to store this data, AND access it later.

I really like the way I can access it, but I can see how this dictionary can get lengthy and hard to read. I'm just looking for an alternative that will let me access the data just as easily as below, but maybe will look less ugly & be more scalable.

```
let oregonLocation = locations["west"]["oregon"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about structs or objects?

Comment: You should clarify your goal. What problem are you having with the data you posted? And you seem to be confused about east and west. :)

Comment: lol just fixed that. I clarified my problem a bit. Just looking for a cleaner way to represent this data.

Comment: I wouldn't put that dictionary in code. Put it in a plist and load the plist at runtime.